# Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'setServicePresenceStatus' of undefined]

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

`Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'setServicePresenceStatus' of undefined]`

This error is related to Omni Channel Presence status availability. Error is occurring only some times but not all the times.

Could you please check and let me know the issue.

Below is the piece of code

```
        window.setTimeout(
            $A.getCallback(function() {
                var omniAPI = component.find("omniToolkit");
                omniAPI.setServicePresenceStatus({
                    statusId: $A.get('$Label.c.CGA_OmniChannel_StatusId'),
                    callback: function(result) {
                        if (result.success) {
                            console.log('Set status successful');
                            console.log(result.statusApiName);
                        } else {
                            console.log('Set status failed');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }), 10000
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `setTimeout` the context of the Aura framework sometimes gets lost, even though you have used `$A.getCallback`.

I suggest moving `var omniAPI = component.find("omniToolkit");` outside the `setTimeout` and then just use its reference inside `$A.getCallback`.

Something like this:

```
var omniAPI = component.find("omniToolkit");
window.setTimeout(
    $A.getCallback(function() {
        omniAPI.setServicePresenceStatus({
            statusId: $A.get('$Label.c.CGA_OmniChannel_StatusId'),
            callback: function(result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    console.log('Set status successful');
                    console.log(result.statusApiName);
                } else {
                    console.log('Set status failed');
                }
            }
        });
    }), 10000
)
```